# Basis Expansion Channel Model

Tags: reference-request, fading-channel

I usually encounter that kind of channel model which is Basis Expansion Channel Model, But I couldn't understand its meaning exactly, and what is it. Could you please help me by providing a simple explanation for it And/Or documents & video which explain it in simple way?

Comment: You could greatly improve your question by providing references to where you encountered the Basis Expansion Channel Model.

Comment: @hops for example here where I've seen and tried to understand what is it, https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/720248/

Comment: Okay, well this seems to be an expansion of the channel in a basis consisting of complex exponentials, proposed by this paper. The general idea comes from functional analysis though. In short, one can view a function as a vector and then construct it from more elementary basis functions (aka basis vectors). This is what they are attempting to do according to their abstract. The math fonts in the paper are all scrambled for me. I'll verify what I'm saying and provide an answer later if I can and no one else has already.

Comment: I'm sorry I haven't had time for a formal write up as I'm working towards some deadlines. Here is a paper that I think may interest you: http://www.eurasip.org/Proceedings/Eusipco/Eusipco2006/papers/1568989323.pdf 

I'll still try to come back and give a write up if time permits.